# How display public google calendar in android app?

Tags: android, xml, calendar, google-calendar-api

Is there some library that permits to display a public google calendar in android app?

Answer (score 3):

## Get the data

You can download public calendars as XML/JSON feed.

Example:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json
```

- Remove the "alt=json" parameter to get an ATOM (XML) feed
- You can find your public calendar id in your calendar settings
- Description of possible parameters: https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/cal_sample

Use Gson or json-simple or any other JSON library to parse the feed.

## Display it

You can either implement your own calendar view or use a third party implementation. Google these (Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow and not allowed to post all the links yet):

- Extended Calendar View
- Caldroid
- android-calendar-view
- [Create your own calendar view](http://caughtinthemobileweb.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/how-to-implement-calendarview-in-android/)

Hope this helps you.